# How to print the slice of the list of words that only includes letters. python? But what am i missing?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, slice

This is what I have so far:

```
    strVar = 'Together We Thrive, Class of 2025!'


    def stringToList(string):
     listRes = list(string.split(" "))
     return listRes


    strVar = 'Together We Thrive, Class of 2025!'
    strVarList = print(stringToList(strVar))
```

I know I need to have append and sort somewhere in there.

These are the instructions:

1. Convert the provided string to a list using a for loop or built-in function and store the result in a new variable.
2. Sort the list.
3. Print the slice of the list that only includes letters.

This what my answer I supposed to look like:

```
    ['C', 'T', 'T', 'W', 'a', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'r', 'r', 's', 's', 't', 'v']
```

Comment: You don't have to "split" string first. Just see what "list(string)" does.

Comment: to get the list of characters of a given string you only need to call list on it, ex: `list(strVar)`

Comment: the for for-loop part of the instruction is a hint for the filtering part, aka keeping only the letter characters, for that you can use the .isalpha method of strings in either a for loop or with the build-in `filter` function

Comment: @Copperfield okay so i got this when I did that:`['C', 'T', 'T', 'W', 'a', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'r', 'r', 's', 's', 't', 'v']`

Comment: @Copperfield how do you do that?

Comment: @MichaelButscher hello, how to sort the list to be alphabetically

Answer (score 2):

Kindly try:

```
sorted([x for x in 'Together We Thrive, Class of 2025!' if x.isalpha()])
```

Or, pass the name of the defined variable.

This outputs:

```
['C',
 'T',
 'T',
 'W',
 'a',
 'e',
 'e',
 'e',
 'e',
 'f',
 'g',
 'h',
 'h',
 'i',
 'l',
 'o',
 'o',
 'r',
 'r',
 's',
 's',
 't',
 'v']
```

Comment: We haven’t used isalpha yet so I can’t use it @CelsiusStingher

Comment: We don't like doing your homework...  But, for a hint try looking up the keyword `in` and seeing `if x in USER_DEFINED_STRING`

Comment: Thanks @VoNWooDSoN. I agree, I am trying to help you solve the issue by providing a way of reaching the expected output given the input data. Not solve a homework.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
strvar = "Together we Thrive, Class of 2025!"

Listt=[ ]

for letter in strvar:
    if (letter.isalpha()):
        Listt.append(letter)

Listt.sort()

print(Listt)
```

Comment: What is isalpha?

Comment: @BreJaNa [str.isalpha](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) is a method form string that tell you is the string is a letter